# How to submit content on a external page?

Tags: php, submit, external

Does anyone know how I can fill in and submit a form which is hosted on a separate server. Say for example, I wanted to fill the form out on http://tools.950buy.com/rss-submit/ but I wanted to do this from a PHP script on my site. Would this be possible? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it from PHP script you should simulate a HTTP POST request. You can do that by using [Client URL library](http://php.net/curl) or [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) function with properly set up `$context` parameter:

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method' => 'POST'
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="http://url.to/script.php">
```

Comment: Oh, as simple as that? Thanks I'll try it out. :)